# how to use lower version gradle in android studio

Tags: android

I have a android project which need to use gradle below 3.0.but I download the android studio 3.0,it said the minimun gradle version is 4.1.next I download the android studio 2.0. set gradle 2.14.1 and build.gradle of root project to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

but the the error show

```
Error:(1, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 2.14.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in F:\vscodesetup\MyApplication5\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Open File

I am confused ,how can i use gradle version 2.14.1 now ?

Comment: same problem. how to use lower version ?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio's Android view

Expand Gradle Scripts and open gradle-wrapper.properties

and Update distributionUrl to -

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2-all.zip
```

and sync Gradle

[image]

Comment: I want to use lower gradle version

Comment: The error says you should upgrade