# how to use the previous version of gradle in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

i know there is a duplicate question but i don't see the answer there , so asking a diff question.

- [how to use lower version gradle in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459865/how-to-use-lower-version-gradle-in-android-studio)
- [How to downgrade to older version of Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892760/how-to-downgrade-to-older-version-of-gradle)

i clicked on gradle upgrade pop up in android studio , and it installed 6.1.1 , currently there are some issues with 6.1.1 version, so i wanted to install the old version 5.6.4 . so i went to  `AS -> file -> project structure ->project` and changed back to old version 5.6.4. then got the following error.

```
Gradle sync failed: Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 5.6.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/sravan/projects/android-project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

it was working fine before upgrade. so just want to go back to 5.6.4.

i reinstalled android studio by deleting all the projects, .gradle files and all. but still did not work.

any thoughts ? where we can setup minimum version ?

Comment: It seems you upgraded your `com.android.tools.build:gradle` as well. The newer version requires gradle 6.1.1. You can find this in the top level `build.gradle` file in the project.

Comment: @Henry i have completed uninstalled AS but still getting same error.
how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

got it resolved:

uninstall the entire android studio

### uninstalling android with the following commands

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.gradle  
rm -Rf ~/.android  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*  
rm -Rf /usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/  
rm -Rf /Users/<username>/.tooling/gradle
```

Remove your project and clone it again and then goto `Gradle Scripts` and open `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change the below url which ever version you need

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.6-all.zip`